# DCEL data structure in LEDA

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, leda

I am using LEDA for a project in which I have to use doubly connected edge list(DCEL) data structure. I have tried planar_map but that did not worked. So Which data structure should i use for implementing the DCEL in LEDA ??

Comment: Are you allowed to use other C++ libraries, or are you stuck with LEDA only?

Comment: Yes I have to do using LEDA only.